# Customer Dimension as Fact Table in Star Schema

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

Can Dimension Table became a fact table as well? For instance, I have a Customer dimension table with standard attributes such as name, gender, etc.

I need to know how many customers were created today, last month, last year etc. using SSAS.

I could create faceless fact table with customer key and date key or I could use the same customer dimension table because it has both keys already.

Is it normal to use Customer Dimension table as both Fact & Dimension?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the question to get a downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a dimension table as fact table as well. In your case, you would just have a single measure which would be the count - assuming there is one record per customer in this customer table. In case you would have more than one record per customer, e. g. as you use a complex [slowly changing dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) logic, you would use a distinct count.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, it is sufficient to run the query directly against the Customer dimension. There is no need to create another table to do that, such as a fact table. In fact it would be a bad idea to do that because you would have to maintain it every day. It is simpler just to run the query on the fly as long as you have time attributes in the customer table itself. In a sense you are using a dimension as a fact but, after all, data is data and can be queried as need be.

Comment: I have a `created_at` (yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss format) column in the DIM_CUSTOMER table. is it better practice to create a relationship with the date and time dimension from the customer dimension? Doing this could broke my star-schema .